# Remove query string from images in the file manager

Tags: ee2, file-manager, querystring

this might sound silly but I can't find help in the documentation. When I upload images in the File Manager, their URL automatically gets a query string at the end, which I would like to remove. Do you know how to do that?

I'm running version 2.9.0,

what happens is that if I copy the link address of an image file from the file manager, the URL I get is something like this: http://www.ecfr.eu/page/-/Luxembourg.jpg?v=1483717036

having a query an version number that I'd like to remove as I'm not using any form of automatic image sizing

Comment: Can you edit your question with example of URL (or screenshot) and EE version you are using?

Comment: Hi! I've added some informatino, I would not know what to screenshot really though!

Comment: Thanks for adding more info. Please find my answer below. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for adding more information in question:

The answer is "YES", You can remove Versioning query string from your file link.

Follow this steps:

1. Open FTP and go to your EE site.
2. Go to `system > expressionengine > controllers > cp`
3. Open file Named `content_files.php`.
4. On line number "370" (Line number may change) you will find `$r['file_name']` array.
5. Change the value `file_location.'?v='.$file['modified_date'],` to `$file_location,`

Note: This is core file change. Update of EE will loose the changes. Do not do this until you have no other choice.